# Why there is VE map if MAP sensor is available

Tags: ecu-mapping

Recently I'm digging deeper into motorcycle EFI topics and I'm not quite sure what is the relationship of VE table and MAP sensor.

I'm trying to figure out why ECUs need VE table if they have MAP, throttle and temperature sensors available being able to calculate amount of air coming in. My understanding is that MAP and temp sensors provide enough data to calculate amount of air so AFR can be calculated. Why VE map is needed then?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!